# How can I use a file as stdin in Python?

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing

I'm writing unit-tests for an application that uses Python's built-in cmd.Cmd class.
I'm writing test-cases to test the shell program, which listens for user input on sys.stdin.
In the constructor arguments for Cmd, there is an stdin parameter.

I have a Shell class that inherits from Cmd:

```py
class Shell(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = "shell"
    prompt = "(shell) "

    def __init__(self, incoming_q, outgoing_q, completekey='tab', stdin=None, stdout=None):
        super().__init__(completekey=completekey, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout)
        self.incoming_q = incoming_q
        self.outgoing_q = outgoing_q

    def parse(self, args):
        cm, args = args.split("+")
        ret = {
            "command": cm,
            "args": [],
            "flags": []
        }
        for arg in tuple(args.split()):
            if arg[0] == "-":
                ret["flags"].append(arg.strip("-"))
            else:
                ret["args"].append(arg)
        return ret

    def do_command(self, args):
        args = self.parse("command+" + args)
        self.outgoing_q.put(args)
        try:
            res = self.incoming_q.get(timeout=100)
            print(res)
        except Exception:
            print("Command timed out")
```

I want to create a Cmd instance and run the cmdloop in a separate process in the test setup.

```py
class TestShellMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.incoming_q = Queue()
        self.outgoing_q = Queue()
        # What I want to do is something like this
        self.stdin = open("test.txt", "w")
        self.shell = Shell(self.incoming_q, self.outgoing_q, stdin=open("test.txt", "r"))
        self.shell.use_rawinput = 0
        self.shell_p = Process(target=self.shell.cmdloop)
        self.shell_p.start()

    def test_command(self):
        self.stdin.write("command\r\n")
        while self.outgoing_q.empty():
            pass
        res = self.outgoing_q.get()
        self.incoming_q.put("RESPONSE RECEIVED")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.shell_p.terminate()
```

The built-in Cmd does the following to read from stdin when it is provided (using sys.stdin by default):

```py
line = self.stdin.readline()
if not len(line):
    line = 'EOF'
else:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Since I am running the loop in a separate process, I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this in Python. I could subclass Queue, and create a readline method for it and use that as stdin.

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue

class FileQueue(Queue):

    def readline(self):
        if self.empty():
            return ""
        else:
            return self.get()
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to trickery that involves taking advantage of duck-typing to make the program think that a Queue is a file object? Considering how cmd.Cmd has stdin as a parameter, I'm guessing that there is an intended way to do this, but the documentation does not have any example usage of passing in stdin.

Comment: You need `self.stdin.flush()` after you write to it so that `Shell` will see what you've written.

Comment: This probably isn't going to work, though. `Cmd` probably stops when it gets `EOF` on its stdin, which will happen if it reads faster than you write to the file.

Comment: @Barmar That is what's occurring, it's grabbing the EOF and trying to run an EOF command, since the line gets replaced with `"EOF"` if the readline return is empty.

Comment: What you need is a pipe. Pass the read end to `Shell`, and write to the write end in your test code.

Comment: Use `os.pipe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.pipe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe).

Anything you write to the write end of the pipe will be read from the read end. `Shell` won't read `EOF` until your test code calls `self.stdin.close()`.

Writing to a pipe is buffered, so you also need to flush after writing to it.

```
class TestShellMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.incoming_q = Queue()
        self.outgoing_q = Queue()
        pipe = os.pipe
        self.stdin = pipe[1]
        self.shell = Shell(self.incoming_q, self.outgoing_q, stdin=pipe[0])
        self.shell.use_rawinput = 0
        self.shell_p = Process(target=self.shell.cmdloop)
        self.shell_p.start()

    def test_command(self):
        self.stdin.write("command\r\n")
        self.stdin.flush()
        while self.outgoing_q.empty():
            pass
        res = self.outgoing_q.get()
        self.incoming_q.put("RESPONSE RECEIVED")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.shell_p.terminate()
        self.stdin.close()
```